# Shilov Linear Algebra, Coordinate transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does he first introduce the transposed version of the transformation matrices? That is, the first column represents the first basis vector in terms of the old basis, not the first row. Then he goes on to concatenate them in the transpose order before finally using their transposed (ie "correct") versions to transform representations.